# JQuery select an element that contains multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I'm probably tired but can't get this one figured out. I have a several elements on the page that contain 2 classes like so:

```
<div class='cen_answer_option, cen_mc'>Some Content</div>
```

I created a simple event listener in jquery that listens for click on the class cen_answer_option:

```
$(document).on("click",".cen_answer_option",function(e){
alert($(this).html()); });
```

If I remove the "cen_mc" class this works. But with the cen_mc class there, I get nothing. Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Your class has a comma , in between. It should be <div class="cen_answer_option cen_mc">Some Content</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has a comma , in between. It should be `<div class="cen_answer_option cen_mc">Some Content</div>`

```js
$(document).on("click",".cen_answer_option",function(e){
alert($(this).html()); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cen_answer_option cen_mc'>Some Content</div>
```

Comment: I would have stared at that for hours. Thanks!